# remove img tag using .remove() attribute jquery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to remove a `<img>` tag from a function using its `id` with `.remove()` attribute but it doesn't work. You can find a simple code of what I am doing below:

```
<script>
function verify(img)
{
   if(/*somecondition*/)
   removetag_setother();
   else
   //do something
}
function removetag_setother()
{
   $("#1").remove();
   text="<p>hello</p>";
   $("body").append(text);
}
</script>
<body>
<img id="1" onclick="verify(this)" src="image1.png">
</body>
```

Reviewing the console logging I got this message:
**ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Comment: Do you have any error in [the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) ? The code we see can't compile for example.

Comment: fairly certain ids can't be numbers

Comment: it works fine [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/5q6CB/) - is there more code that might be causing this to not work?

Comment: @Jack Numerical IDs have been standardized/made valid in HTML5. Older browsers usually support that as well.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I'll keep that in mind for when IE8 and below don't exist, hopefully some day...

Comment: @Jack Well yeah, IE9 supposedly has standardized behavior, though I believe not even IE6 would clog up on that either. Either way, I agree that just because we can do something doesn't mean that we should  - variables and functions naming never start with a number, why would we use that for IDs/classes identifiers. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the empty `if` and `else` statements. Replace `if(/*somecondition*/)` with `if(true)` and comment out the `else` clause.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function verify(img)
{
   if(true)
       removetag_setother();
   //else
       //do something
}
function removetag_setother()
{
   $("#1").remove();
   text="<p>hello</p>";
   $("body").append(text);
}
</script>
<body>
```

Comment: I put /*somecondition*/ only to give an example. I have a alert message inside removetag_setother() function at the beginning and this shows its content, however, when the command $("#1").remove() is executed neither the text var is set nor the .append() command is executed.

Comment: Is the else clause empty in your code? You'll get a compile error if it is because it sees the function's closing `}` as your else statment.

Comment: Else clause is for a call to another function. I am sure that the call to the removetag_setother() function is done because I can see the alert message that I put inside it. I don't know how to catch the error when the $("#1").remove() is executed. Do you have any idea to catch the error??

Comment: What browser are you using? You should see an error in the console. The call to `$("#1").remove()` is your first jQuery call, are you sure you have jQuery included on your page?

Comment: My browser is Firefox. I got the console error:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Ok, so jQuery is missing. Put this in the head section of your page: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` I also updated the example in the answer, that should work.

Comment: Thank you Clav, that worked. Nevertheless, I wonder why this script didn't work:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>